# remove elements with repeated attribute using lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I've got a list of Person objects like this:

```
list.add(new Person("John", 20)); //person is just name and age
list.add(new Person("Maria", 21));
list.add(new Person("John", 40));
list.add(new Person("Carl", 10));
```

The resulting list must have no persons with the same name, regardless of age, so only 3 elements would survive. How can this be accomplished using Java 8 lambda expressions?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
Set<String> unique = new HashSet<>();
list.removeIf(e -> !unique.add(e.getName()));
```

Note, that the Person class needs to have a getter to return the name of the person.

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the `hashCode()` and `equals()`. Then you can use this:

```
List<Person> collect = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: distinct here would apply to the object, not to the name itself..

Comment: That's probably why he suggests to overwrite `equals` and `hashCode` with the corresponding logic (two persons are equal iff they have the same name).

Comment: yes, but that's a pretty bad practice. Saying an object is equals to another object just based on a single attribute and not the rest is bad design only intended for a particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the list into a map in which they key is Person::getName and the value is the object itself, and if they are equal choose the first one, then get the map values which is a Collection, and lastly convert to a List

```
list = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Person:getName, Function.Identity(), 
(a, b) -> a)).values().stream().collect(Collections.toList());
```

Comment: This would be Map, weren't you looking for list as result?

Comment: See that at the end is collected to a list

Answer (score 0):

This could easily be done using `Comparator`. As this is really flexible to use and also allows multiple comparison criteria as per your need. See code below:-

```
    Set<Person> expectedOutput = new TreeSet<>((person1, person2) ->
            person1.getName().equals(person2.getName()) ? 0 : 1
    );
    list.listIterator().forEachRemaining(expectedOutput::add);
```

I personally will avoid overriding equals for a fluctuating criteria. For example, If i say that my objects are equal if names are equal in one scenario and in other scenario I say my objects are equal if ages are equal. Then it's better to use `comparator`.